# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mypackage.Address1

Tags: hibernate

**hibernate.cf.xml file**

```
<hibernate-configuration>        
<session-factory>  

 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>  
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>  
 <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>  
 <property name="connection.username">system</property>
 <property name="connection.password">Password</property>  
 <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>  
         
 <mapping class="com.mypackage.UserDetails"/>
 <!-- <mapping class="com.mypackage.Address1"/> -->
   
 </session-factory>        
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**UserDetails Entity**

```
package com.mypackage;

@Entity
@Table(name="UserDetailsTable")
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue//(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    
    private String userName;
    @Embedded
    private Address1 address;
    
    private String phoneNo;
    private Date date;
}
```

**Embeddable Entity**

```
package com.mypackage;

@Embeddable
public class Address1 {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String pincode;     
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class Test {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Session session=new AnnotationConfiguration().
                configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
        
        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
        Address1 addrobj1=new Address1();
        addrobj1.setStreet("abcd");
        addrobj1.setCity("efgh");
        addrobj1.setState("abcd");
        addrobj1.setPincode("123456");
        
        UserDetails obj1=new UserDetails();
        obj1.setUserId(1);
        obj1.setUserName("John");
        obj1.setAddress(addrobj1);
        obj1.setPhoneNo("1234567890");
        
        session.saveOrUpdate(addrobj1);         
        t.commit();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("saved successfully");
    }    
}
```

error getting on eclipse juno is:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
> (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version). log4j:WARN Please initialize
> the log4j system properly. Exception in thread "main"
> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mypackage.Address1
> at
> org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:548)
> at
> org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1338)
> at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:180)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:487)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:84)
> at
> org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
> at
> org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:507)
> at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:499)
> at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:495)
> at com.mypackage.Test.main(Test.java:33)

Couldn't sort out the error.
Someone please help??

Answer (score 1):

You have commented mapping class Address1 `<!-- <mapping class="com.mypackage.Address1"/> -->` so it can't be found

Answer (score 0):

Please add the mapping tag for Address1 bean in  to your hibernate configuration file and if you havnt created the mapping file for your Address1 bean then create it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Address1" table="ADDRESS1">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the address detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="street" column="street_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="city" column="city_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="state" column="state_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="zipcode" column="zipcode" type="string"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

you can also use the below tag to add entity mapping in your configuration file

```
  <mapping resource>com/mypackage/Address1.hbm.xml</mapping resource>
```

or you must explicitly add the class to the configuration using

```
configuration.addClass(com.mypackage.Address1.class)
// Read mappings as a application resourceName
 // addResource is for add hbml.xml files in case of declarative approach
configuration.addResource("com.mypackage.Address1.xml")
```